# image does not show up. Django

Tags: html, django, django-templates

Can not find what I'm doing wrong (I guess it should be some syntax error). My pictures does not showing up. I'm getting "NO FILES".

## html

```
    <!-- RECENTLY ADDED FILES -->
        <div class="buttom-box floatleft">
            <h3>Recently Added Files</h3>
                <p>New class papers. Now you can enjoy and study them</p>
                <br>
                {% if recent_files %}
                    {% for file in recent_files %}
                        <img src="{{ MEDIA_URL }}{{ file.image }}" alt="Sample 1" width="125" height="125" />
                    {% endfor %}
                {% else %}
                    <p>NO FILES</p>
                {% endif %}
        </div>
```

## views.py

```
def index(request):  
    recent_files = FileDescription.objects.all()

    context_instance=RequestContext(request)
    return render_to_response('index.html', 
        {'recent_files':recent_files,},
        context_instance,
        )
```

## MySQL for FileDescription:

```
mysql> SELECT * FROM school_filedescription;
+----+------------+--------------+-----------+------------------+-----------+------------------+---------------------+---------------------+-----------------------------+
| id | subject_id | subject_name | file_type | file_uploaded_by | file_name | file_description | file_creation_time  | file_modified_time  | image                       |
+----+------------+--------------+-----------+------------------+-----------+------------------+---------------------+---------------------+-----------------------------+
|  1 |          1 | Math 140     | class     | rrr              | lalala    | lalala           | 2012-08-23 12:12:12 | 2012-08-23 12:12:12 | files/rrr/class/smart.jpg   |
|  2 |          1 | Math 140     | class     | rrr              | ,s,s,s    | s msms           | 2012-08-23 12:32:39 | 2012-08-23 12:32:39 | files/rrr/class/smart_1.jpg |
+----+------------+--------------+-----------+------------------+-----------+------------------+---------------------+---------------------+-----------------------------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

However this code in the other page works fine

## other page:

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% block main-menu %}
    <div class="contentarea">       
        <img src="{{ MEDIA_URL }}{{ picture.image }}"/>
    </div>
{% endblock %}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding the recent file parameter to your request context instance, like this:

```
context_instance = RequestContext(request, {
  'recent_files': recent_files
})
```

and then call the request like this...

```
return render_to_response('index.html', context_instance = context_instance)
```

Comment: In terms of "why" - render_to_response only uses the context_instance variable to render the template ( https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/shortcuts/#django.shortcuts.render_to_response ).  I don't know what the dictionary argument is even for to be honest; I only know that context_instance is the only variable used when rendering templates that way.  So using my suggestion puts the data you're trying to get into the template where django is looking for it.